# MMP and finite generation of Cox rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a $Q$-factorial projective variety. If $Cox (X) $ is finitely generated, do this imply that the MMP terminates for X?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert but do your conditions imply $X$ is a Mori dream space?

Comment: Read Hu--Keel, "Mori dream spaces and GIT".

Comment: Actually you just need finite generation of certain adjoint rings: From: {\it New outlook on the Minimal Model Program, II}, arXiv:1005:0614 " We prove that the finite generation of adjoint rings proved in [Cascini and Lazi\'c] implies all the foundational results of the Minimal Model Program: the Rationality, Cone and Contraction theorems, the existence of flips, and termination of flips with scaling in the presence of a big boundary."